# how to switch to a new database

Tags: django, django-models

I want to deploy my django project to the production environments, and  associated it with an new empty database, and I did as follows :

1. Create an new empty database
2. Updated settings.py and pointed the database name to the new one
3. Deleted the migrations folder under my App
4. Run python manage.py runserver and no errors returned
5. Run python manage.py makemigrations and python manage.py migrate

but only auth related tables created ( like `auth_user` , `auth_group` ... ),  no databases tables created for my Apps

How should I do for this situation to move to the new database for my project?

Comment: Can you tell me the output of: from django.conf import settings; print settings.DATABASES and settings.INSTALLED_APPS

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> 3. Deleted the migrations folder under my App

This was your mistake, you deleted the migrations - including the initial migrations. So when you go to `makemigrations` you haven't got the initial migration available.

So you need to run `makemigrations <app_name>` to at least get the initial migration.

If you were to do this again, don't delete the migrations, just change the database settings and then migrate.

Comment: Aside from the missing migrations, will such an approach work? I am trying to develop a simple app using SQLite and then switch it to MySQL when in-production.

Comment: @MadPhysicist - Thats the intended practice - If you need further help, consider asking a new question complete with what you've tried/researched

Comment: @Sayse i have not tried this yet. I want to make sure i am not taking a failing route before i even begin :)

Answer (score 14):

Firstly, you should not have deleted the migrations. Now, make all the migrations again which you have deleted.

```
python manage.py makemigrations app_name
```

Do this for all the apps of which you have deleted the migrations.
Now, add your new database to settings.py. Do not remove the old one yet. For example, if I were adding a MySQL database, I would have added the following to the DATABASES dictionary in settings.py:

```
'new': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'databasename',
    'USER': 'databaseusername',
    'PASSWORD': 'databasepassword',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'PORT': '3306',
}
```

I have named the database as 'new'. Now we have two databases 'default' and 'new'. Now you have to create tables in the new database by running the migrations on the new database:

```
python manage.py migrate --database=new
```

You can follow these additional steps if you want to transfer your data to the new database. First, clear the new database:

```
python manage.py flush --database=new
```

Now export data from the old database into a json file:

```
python manage.py dumpdata>data.json
```

Import this data into the new database:

```
python manage.py loaddata data.json --database=new
```

Now you can remove the 'default' database and rename the 'new' database to 'default'.

The procedure mentioned in this answer is taken from [my blog](https://pythonfusion.com/switch-database-django/).

Comment: relation new does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Just check the output of `python manage.py makemigrations` command, if it is showing no change detected then you need to check that have you added that app in your `INSTALLED_APPS = []` in `settings.py` file or it might be the problem because you have deleted migration folder.Because if is there any database connectivity error it will show you that while doing makemigrations.

Answer (score 0):

If your database has a new name, i.e. not "default", you need to specify it to `migrate`:

```
python manage.py migrate --database <newdb>
```

Answer (score 0):

I also made a migration and used [Umer's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8868448/umer) answer, but encountered this error when running
`python manage.py loaddata data.json --database=new`:
`json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 2 (char 1)`

Fixed it by using the `--output` option for `dumpdata` instead of redirect and excluding tables `auth.permission` and `contenttypes`:

`python3 manage.py dumpdata --exclude auth.permission --exclude contenttypes --output data.json`

Information about excluding tables is from [here](https://coderwall.com/p/mvsoyg/django-dumpdata-and-loaddata)

[dumpdata reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/django-admin/#dumpdata)