# How do I transfer test database to product database

Tags: python, django, migration

I'm working on an Django project, and building and testing with a database on GCP. Its full of test data and kind of a mess.

Now I want to release the app with a new and fresh another database.

How do I migrate to the new database? with all those `migrations/` folder?

I don't want to delete the folder cause the development might continue.

Data do not need to be preserved. It's test data only.

Django version is 2.2;
Python 3.7

Thank you.

＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝ update

After changing the `settings.py`, `python manage.py makemigrations` says no changes detected.

Then I did `python manage.py migrate`, and now it complains about relation does not exist.

=============== update2

The problem seems to be that, I had a table name `Customer`, and I changed it to 'Client'. Now it's complaining about "psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "app_customer" does not exist".

How can I fix it, maybe without deleting all files in `migrations/`?

================ update final

After eliminating all possibilities, I have found out that the "new" database is not new at all. I migrated on that database some months ago.

Now I created a fresh new one and `migrate` worked like a charm.

Again, thank you all for your suggestions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to switch to a new database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38067164/how-to-switch-to-a-new-database)

Comment: @dspencer No. Already did that. Please check the update.

Comment: Could you add the full error when you run migrate?  Also, if you run makemigrations after connecting to a fresh new blank database where the only thing there is the database name and it states "no changes detected", you must still be connected to the original database.  The reason for that is Django saves what migrations it has applied in the database so it knows not to run them again.  It appears its still referencing the original database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The migration folder is your friend.  No need to delete it.  You can flatten migrations if you feel the migration folder is getting too large with many migration files, but you don't need to.

If you plan to use a new database in GCP, just change the `settings.py` file, which is typically located in the `project_name/project_name/` folder.  Locate the DATABASES section to reflect the new database credentials.

Once your app is pointing at the new database, run `python manage.py migrate`.  This will build the database schema with the necessary tables to start populating the new database.

Comment: I thought `migrate` on a new database would go through all the `migrations/*.py` files. So it won't do that, instead, `migrate` will just create newest version of my tables on the new database?

Comment: It will go through the migration files, but those don't collect any data, they just keep track of the models and make changes to the database structure.  I understand the confusion, but migrate in Django means, migrate the database structure to a specified database, not the data inside of it.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Could you please check the update? How could I fix that error.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to delete any migrations/ folder, you can use the same migration files in product database, if you don't need the test data just delete the database i.e. db.sqlite3 (I guess you are using default database).
Note: Migration files don't effect your database structure(if you delete and do makemigrations or use the existing one it remains the same)

Comment: I thought migrate on a new database would go through all the migrations/*.py files. Thank you, learned something new today.